# kafka stream task partition number

Tags: stream, apache-kafka, task, partition

source topic "streams-wordcount" have 4 Partitions, when I start the kafka the stream job, why show 8 tasks in console?

```
current active tasks: [0_0, 0_1, 1_0, 0_2, 1_1, 0_3, 1_2, 1_3]
current standby tasks: []
previous active tasks: []
```

Comment: who decide the number of task? is one partition corresponds to one task?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Kafka has a default topic replication factor of 1, this might be the cause. Topic replication is used for higher durability and fault tolerance.